# Side bar hyperlink are not hidden by height css

Tags: css

CSS

```
.nested-menu {
        .list-group-item {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .nested {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        ul.submenu {
            height: 0;
        }
        & .expand {
            ul.submenu {
                list-style-type: none;
                height: auto;
                li {
                    a {
                        color: #FFF;
                        padding: 10px;
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="nested-menu">
                <a class="list-group-item" (click)="addExpandClass('pages')">
                    <span>
                        <i class="fa fa-universal-access"></i>
                        &nbsp;Account
                    </span>
                </a>
                <div class="nested" [class.expand]="showMenu === 'pages'">
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a [routerLink]="['account/password']" (click)="eventCalled()">
                                <span>Password reset</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a [routerLink]="['account/user']" (click)="eventCalled()">
                                <span>User</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

before clicking it looks like this. `height: 0` is not hiding the child links. How to hide them ?

[image]

Comment: You need to add `overflow: hidden;` to ul.submenu.

Comment: @Viandoks : Cool. Put as answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add overflow:hidden; to your submenu class.

```
ul.submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the height for inline elements. You will have to convert that to either `block` element or `inline-block` element to be able to do it.

Set `display: inline-block;` or `display: block;`